# Two buttons in one UITableViewCell

Tags: ios4, uitableview

How do you place two buttons in one UITableViewCell like this example from the Apple App store?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:kButtonTag] == nil) {

    UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn1.tag = kButtonTag;
    UIButton *btn2 = btn1;
    [btn1 setTitle:@"Tell a Friend" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setTitle:@"Report a Problem" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,100,40);
    btn2.frame = CGRectMake(120, 0,100, 40);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn2];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}
```

Change the frames around, and it should look similar.